# Passing parameters through nested functions

Tags: r, dynamic

I am passing the same parameters through multiple functions, part of the code looking like

```
inner.integral <-function(f,n,i,x,odds,alpha,beta)
{ 
 beta.func(x,alpha,beta) * ( beta.prob(alpha,beta) * eval(call(paste("func",as.character(i),as.character(alpha+1),sep=".")),(x*(1+f*odds)))+(1-beta.prob(alpha,beta))*eval(call(paste("func",as.character(i),as.character(alpha),sep=".")),(x*(1-f))))
}

inner.integral.int <- function(f,n,i,x,odds,alpha,beta) {
  integrate(inner.integral,lower=0,upper=1,n=n,i=i,
             x=x,odds=odds,alpha=alpha,beta=beta)
}

inner.integral.int.2 <- function(f,n,i,x,odds,alpha,beta) {
  y <- inner.integral.int(f,n,i,x,odds,alpha,beta)$value
  return(y)
}
```

When passing parameters into `inner.integral.int.2`, via the optimise function, something like:

```
optimise(inner.integral.int.2,lower=min.f,
          upper=max.f,n=n,i=i,x=x,odds=odds,alpha=a,beta=b)
```

for defined min.f, max.f, n, i, x etc I receive the error:

```
Error in paste("func", as.character(i), as.character(alpha + 1), sep = ".") : 
  argument "i" is missing, with no default
```

What have I done wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first thing you should do is clean up your code.  You don't want to have a single line of code that is 245 characters long.

You also should avoid `eval(call(paste(` unless it is absolutely necessary, and here it is not.  At the very least, you could switch to using `do.call` which can be passed a character string and a list of inputs, and doesn't require creating a `call` object.  But the better thing to do would be to avoid manipulating function names as strings, and either define `func` to take `i` and `alpha` as inputs (as well as the current input), or else create a list of functions `func[[i]]` each of which takes `alpha` as an input.

Most likely, if you do this, the problem will either go away or become apparent.

Answer (score 0):

I think you may be running into problems with R's lazy evaluation. Your example is pretty complicated (look at all the parameters you have included), but as a first step, try adding the line:

```
force(i)
```

in your functions, i.e.

```
inner.integral.int <- function(f,n,i,x,odds,alpha,beta) {
    force(i)
    integrate(inner.integral,lower=0,upper=1,n=n,i=i,
             x=x,odds=odds,alpha=alpha,beta=beta)
}
```

See `?force` for details.